# Still returning a 403 despite rights assigned

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi

I have set up a new Pi with the latest Raspbian Jessie, 4.1.13+.

My `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` has the following:

```
Alias /home /Z/webhome/
<Directory "/Z/webhome/">
   Options All
   Options -Indexes
   AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
```

And `/Z/webhome` is as follows:

```
pi@Paganini:~ $ ls -al /Z/webhome
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Dec 15 11:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi pi 4096 Dec 15 11:30 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  162 Dec 15 11:44 test.py
```

And `www-data` is a member of group `pi`:

```
pi@Paganini:~ $ groups www-data
www-data : www-data pi
```

However, getting `http://paganini/home/test.py` gives a 403 (`You don't have permission to access /home/test.py on this server.`). Using a non-existent file, eg `/home/test2.py` also gives a 403, and not a 404.

The above set-up works in another older Pi (3.18.11+). Has something changed or what have I done incorrectly?

Comment: Have you checked if selinux is enabled? This can cause permissions to be denied unless you set the context of the directories and files properly. Try running `ls -aZ /Z/webhome`. Post the output. Post the output of `getenforce` as well.

Comment: Hearing of selinux for the first time.  ls -aZ gives: `? .  ? ..  ? test.py`.  getenforce command is not found.

Comment: Can you add these 2 directives within the `<Directory>...</Directory>` block? `AllowOverride None` and `Require all granted`.

Comment: That solves the access problem! Thanks. But instead of running the file through Python, it merely output its contents.